How can I make a camera follow an instantiated object at runtime?
I have an object meant to represent a player that I'd like to spawn in at runtime. Because it is instantiated at runtime, I'm not sure about how to get the main camera in my scene to follow the instance of the player object.
In a camera script (which is attached to the camera), I have the following:
public Transform cameraTarget; // i.e. the player's transform component
public Transform cameraLocation;
private int offset = -10;
//...

private void TrackTarget();
{
    transform.position = new (cameraTarget.transform.position.x,
                              cameraTarget.transform.position.y,
                              cameraTarget.transform.position.z + offset);
}

In a separate game manager script, I'm instantiating the player, then attempting to "assign" the camera to it like so:
public Player player;
public Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    InstancePlayer();
    player.transform = mainCamera.cameraTarget;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (mainCamera.cameraTarget != null)
    {
        mainCamera.TrackTarget();
    }
}

private void InstancePlayer()
{
    Vector2 startLocation = Vector2.zero; // using `Vector2.zero` as a placeholder for now
    Instantiate(player, startLocation, Quaternion.identity);
}

Perhaps unsurprisingly, this is not a working solution (or if it is, I'm missing how to implement it properly), so to resummarize the question: how might I make the camera follow my instanced player object?
EDIT: Possible clarification -- the player instantiates and shows up in the Unity hierarchy as "Player(Clone)" when the game is running. I think that, if I understand what I'm doing, I'm trying to target the clone with the camera and have the camera follow after successfully obtaining a target, in this case.
EDIT 2: After consulting this StackOverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037208/is-there-any-way-to-assign-player-to-camera-after-the-game-started-in-unity), I attempted the first suggested method, and initially did not find success with what I had above, so I reattempted in a separate project using similar code:
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // some code to control movement
}

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cameraTarget;
    public Player player;
    private readonly int offset = -10;

    public void AssignTarget(Player player)
    {
        this.player = player;
        cameraTarget = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // I initially made this function private and didn't notice...oops!
    public void TrackTarget()
    {
        transform.position = new (cameraTarget.transform.position.x,
                                  cameraTarget.transform.position.y,
                                  cameraTarget.transform.position.z + offset);
    }
}

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public CameraController camController;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        InstancePlayer();
        camController.AssignTarget(camController.player);
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (camController.cameraTarget != null)
        {
            camController.TrackTarget();
        }
    }

    private void InstancePlayer()
    {
        Vector2 startPosition = Vector2.zero;
        GameObject myPlayer = Instantiate(player, startPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        camController.player = myPlayer.GetComponent<Player>();
    }
}

This solution obtains both a clone of the transform and a clone of the script component belonging to the Player prefab, although I think that only the clone of the transform is necessary to get it working. I'll be completely honest, though--I don't entirely understand why this works, and I'm not confident that it's as concise as it could be (i.e. there may be extraneous code that doesn't really get used). What I think I have figured out is that it might have been necessary to use GetComponent<>() to obtain the clone of the transform from the prefab.
In any case, here's an example of how the camera follows the instantiated Player object, along with some reference images:




Although I was able to answer your question, when you have something that "is not a working solution", you should describe what's specifically gone wrong (e.g. specific error messages that you've encountered).

While it is certainly possible to do this using scripting, I would recommend you to look into Cinemachine.  It contains a "follow" mode for cameras to automatically follow a game object (or a group of game objects as a "target group") and many more useful features to give your game really cool camera controls with almost no scripting required.

@Kevin I would have included error messages, but that's part of the issue: I'm not receiving error messages (and yes, they are turned on in the console). I'll take a look at your answer here in just a moment--I do get the feeling that it was probably something as stupid as failing to order things properly, as you suggested.

@NJJ_002 Your original code has multiple syntax errors which should have caused the compiler to throw error messages and prevented you from testing. If you were not getting errors, then something is wrong with your project or the way you've added your code to the project.

Or, if the code you posted is not your original code - don't do that. We can't help you if you rewrite the code for your post and your rewritten code has different mistakes than the original code.

@Kevin Or there was nothing that it knew to throw an error on? I tried in a separate test project where I think I put together a working solution (edit / answer to follow shortly), and the same situation occurred, where no errors cropped up unless I purposely disconnected a reference in the editor. And I’m not certain as to why you’re implying that this is not something that I wrote myself. A little bit of goodwill goes a long way. Regardless, I fixed the syntax errors that I found in my post so that hopefully it’s not a sticking point—I didn’t copy/paste my code, I just make mistakes.

@NJJ_002 What I meant was sometimes people don't paste the code they wrote into the question box here (because it's formatted badly or has things they don't want to share or whatever). Instead, they rewrite their own code in the question box, but make mistakes that weren't in their original code. "there was nothing that it knew to threw an error on" makes no sense. You can't even compile a project with the mistakes that are in your question; you'll get compiler errors.

As for your updated question - if the Player is an object in the scene, you shouldn't need to instantiate a new copy of it to make the camera follow it. If the Player was a prefab that wasn't located in the scene, then instantiating a copy is necessary to  put the player into the scene. I'm not sure what else I can offer at this point other that to suggest that you spend some time on your Unity fundamentals.

Camera is the name of a built-in component in Unity. You should not name your component Camera, and you should refer to your component by its type.
public class FollowCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform cameraTarget // i.e. the player's transform component
    public Transform cameraLocation
    private int offset = -10;

    private void Update() {
        if (cameraTarget == null) return;
        transform.position = new Vector3(cameraTarget.transform.position.x,
                                  cameraTarget.transform.position.y,
                                  cameraTarget.transform.position.z + offset);
    }
}

You can assign the target like this:
public FollowCamera mainCamera; // Note the type.

private void Start() {
    InstancePlayer();
    mainCamera.cameraTarget = player.transform; // Note the order.
}

Also, take note that you had the original assignment statement backwards:
player.transform = mainCamera.cameraTarget;

This is trying to assign the value of mainCamera.cameraTarget to the player.transform property, which is an invalid operation since transform is a read-only property.

So here's the issue that I'm having now: it looks like all of the references are assigned properly and everything is ordered correctly, but the camera does not move with the player, and there are no generated error messages. Any idea why?

To clarify, I've also been using Debug.Log() to try to suss out why this is the case, and the messages are all populating in the console when they should.

@NJJ_002 The FollowCamera component must be attached to the same GameObject as the Unity Camera component. In FollowCamera's Update() method, add Debug.Log(cameraTarget.transform.position.ToString()). Also take note that your original code was missing the Vector3 constructor; I've added that.

The FollowCamera component was attached as you specified. As an aside, I’ve been using Visual Studio 2022, and I kept getting a message (something like “new statement can be simplified”) which seemed to indicate that the Vector3 constructor was unnecessary—I’m guessing that it’s because the structure (float, float, float) is automatically interpreted as a Vector3, but not sure if that’s why; either way, it was working as intended.
